# Android Studio import error

Tags: android, android-studio

Just trying out Android Studio. I have exported my project Gradle file from Eclipse and imported it into Android Studio.

The project will not build in Android Studio, it fails with a message saying

IllegalStateException: Unable to find Gradle home directory for project 'NVRRClubApp': Unable to find Gradle home directory for project 'NVRRClubApp'

I have no idea what my Gradle home directory should be, or even where to set it. I was hoping the import would have fixed that for me.

Any ideas how to start fixing this?

Comment: I have the same problem with gradle home dir. How to setup it for my imported project?

Answer (score 1):

**Gradle** needs a home directory to store its junk, like git.
Choose a directory that is convenient for how your store your development files.
Something that will get backed up when you back up your work.

Mine is:
C:\Documents and Settings\GeorgeDeVargas\My Documents\Software

You will then likely get some java null pointer errors as you configure Android:

See http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/error_compilejava_java_lang_nullpointerexception_no_error_message

Comment: Do you know how to check my home dir for gradle? (I have C:/User/name/.gradle)